# Time complexity min num of array

Tags: python, arrays, time, decorator, min

I just started learning data structures & algos in Python and came upon the following question:

"Write two Python functions to find the minimum number in a list. The first function should compare each number to every other number on the list. O(n^2). The second function should be linear O(n)."

```
from misc.decorator_timer import my_timer


def main():
    """
    Finds the minimum number in a list
    findMin1:  O(n^2)
    findMin2:  O(n)
    """
    findMin1(list(range(10**6)))
    findMin1(list(range(10**7)))
    findMin2(list(range(10**6)))
    findMin2(list(range(10**7)))


@my_timer
def findMin1(array):
    """Finds min number in a list in O(n^2) time"""
    for i in range(len(array)):
        min_val = array[i]
        for num in array:
            if num < min_val:
                min_val = num
        return min_val


@my_timer
def findMin2(array):
    """Finds min number in a list in O(n) time"""
    min_val = array[0]
    for num in array:
        if num < min_val:
            min_val = num
    return min_val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tested it with a timer decorator I made below:

```
# ./misc/decorator_timer.py

import time
from functools import wraps


def my_timer(func):
    """Adds how long it took to run"""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t0 = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        timedelta = time.time() - t0

        print(f'\nfunction:\t"{func.__name__}"\nruntime:\t {timedelta:.08} sec')

        return result

    return wrapper
```

This is the result I get:

```
function:   "findMin1" 
runtime:    0.03258419 sec

function:   "findMin1" 
runtime:    0.35547304 sec

function:   "findMin2" 
runtime:    0.035234928 sec

function:   "findMin2" 
runtime:    0.33552194 sec
```

Obviously linear is better, but why is `findMin1` growing linearly, not quadratically as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement is inside the outer for loop, hence you only execute the outer loop once and then immediately return. Because of this, the first method has complexity O(n).

If you de-indent `return min_val` once, moving it outside the outer for loop, you get quadratic complexity.

Comment: Oops! Totally missed that. Thanks!